# Tedious fraction decomposition integral $\int\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2} \, dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I'm having this integral to resolve using fraction decomposition:

$$\int\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2} \, dx$$

This gives me the following:

$$\frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{C}{x-1} + \frac{D}{(x-1)^2} = \frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}$$

Which results in a 4 variables system of equation...

Is there a quick way to resolve this that I'm missing out?

Comment: The right side should be $\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}$, not $1$.  A method that speeds a lot of these up is Heaviside's method:  clear denominators, and plug in the roots of your polynomial in one at a time.  That gives a few relations that you may use to speed up what you're trying to do.

Comment: Another method would be substituting $x=\sec \theta$, then breaking the transformed integral down into sines and cosines, and then performing a $u$-sub.  But since it said to specifically use partial-fraction decomposition...

Comment: Or:  type "partial fraction decomposition for 1/(1-x^2)^2" into http://wolframalpha.com.  Once you have the decomposition, you can check that it is correct by making a common denominator.  This is a perfectly valid way to produce a decomposition, although if this is for homework, it may not be one that your grader accepts.

Answer (score 3):

You can work out the partial fraction decomposition of the integrand by repeat application of the identify:
$$\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)} = \frac{1}{(b-a)}\left[\frac{1}{x-a} - \frac{1}{x-b}\right]$$
This is especially useful when $a,b$ are small integers.
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}
&= \left[\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}\right]^2 =
\frac14\left[\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1}\right]^2\\
&= \frac14\left[\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{2}{(x-1)(x+1)} + \frac{1}{(x+1)}^2\right]\\
&= \frac14\left[\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} - \left(\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1}\right) + \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right]\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively start from $\frac{1}{(x^2-a)^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{1}{(x^2-a)}$, then determine $\int\frac{1}{(x^2-a)} \, dx$ (this is straight forward to put the integrand into partial fractions), differentiate this wrt $a$ then set $a=1$.